# how to set app open ad backgroung color in android?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, google-ad-manager

My code is here!
appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);`appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(fullScreenContentCallback); currentActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); appOpenAd.show(currentActivity);`

The link below in which app open ad have black color when ad is showing.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freescanner.qrcodereader.barcodescanner.barcodereader.socialmobileapps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am looking for how to add background color in app open ad, when app shows app open ad then content of main screen are not showing it shows black color behind the google app open ad, after dismiss the ad the content are showing fine, but how this is possible? The given link of app are working like this:                                                           https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freescanner.qrcodereader.barcodescanner.barcodereader.socialmobileapps

Answer (score 1):

first create a file theme.xml and copy the code given below.

```
<resources>
 <style name="myAdTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

after this just ad these lines to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AdTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme"
/>
```